# OpenGL Move Polygons across screen

Tags: c++, opengl

I have 2 polygons on either side of the screen that are rotating in a circle. What I'm trying to do is have both these polygons move along the x axis as they are rotating and so eventually they will overlap in the middle but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
glm::mat4 model_view = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0), glm::vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.8));
model_view = glm::translate(model_view, glm::vec3(-3.0, 0.0, 0.0));
model_view = glm::rotate(model_view, 5*rotate_value, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0, 1.0f));

glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, &model_view[0][0]);

glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, NumVertices);

//Object 2
glm::mat4 model_view2 = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0), glm::vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.8));
model_view2 = glm::translate(model_view2, glm::vec3(2.0, 0.0, 0.0));
model_view2 = glm::rotate(model_view2, 5 * rotate_value, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0f));

glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, &model_view2[0][0]);

//Starting the pipeline
glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, NumVertices);
```

Comment: This seems right. What is your issue? BTW, `GL_POLYGON`  is for OpenGL < 3.2 or using a *Compatibility Profile*. I recomend using OGL >=3.2 *Core Profile*, which means you have to draw the polygons as lines.

Comment: Both these polygons are just rotating in the same spot. I want the left polygon to move to the right and the right polygon to move to the left where they will eventually overlap in the middle. So each polygon is performing 2 actions, the first is the rotation which works, and the second is the translation along x axis which doesn't work

Comment: Aha!  I thought this [looked familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089161).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm trying to do is have both these polygons move along the x axis as they are rotating and so eventually they will overlap in the middle but I'm not sure how to do this.

To this you have to calculate the rotation and translation in dependence of the time. The rotation angle and the translation vector is a function of the time.

To do so you have to know the period of time which is passed since the start of the animation, at every time point, when the scene is rendered.
One possibility to calculate the passed time is to use [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now/). Store the current time point at the start of the animation. Calculate the difference of two time points in every frame to get the past period of time.

e.g. The following code calculates a period of time in seconds as a value of type `double`, with an accuracy of milliseconds:

```
#include <chrono>
```

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start_time =
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point current_time =
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto delta_time = current_time - start_time;
double time_s = 
    (double)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(delta_time).count() / 1000.0;
```

To calculate an angle in dependent of the time you have to define the rotations per second. Divide the period of time by the number of seconds and multiply the result with `360` for degrees respectively `2*PI` for radians:

```
float rot_per_s = 10.0f; // 10 full rotations per second
float angle_deg = (float)(360.0 * time_s / rot_per_s);
```

To create a uniform movement from one point to another and the way back, the start and the end point have to be defined and the period of time for the full way.
With this information the translation vector at a time point can be linear interpolated between the start point and the end point pf the movement:

```
double    motiontime_s = 5.0f;  // from start to end and back in 5 seconds
glm::vec3 start_pt1    = .....; // start point of the movement
glm::vec3 end_pt1      = .....; // end point of the movement

double times;
double pos_rel   = modf(time_s / motiontime_s, &times);
float  w         = pos_rel < 0.5 ? (float)pos_rel * 2.0f : (float)(1.0 - pos_rel) * 2.0f;
glm::vec3 trans1 = start_pt1 * (w-1.0f) + end_pt1*w;
```

With the angle and the translation vector the model matrices for the objects can be computed and scene can be drawn:

```
float rot_per_s = 1.0f/5.0f; // 1 full rotations in 5 second
float angle_deg = (float)(360.0 * time_s * rot_per_s);

double    motiontime_s = 5.0f; // from start to end and back in 5 seconds
glm::vec3 start_pt1    = .....;
glm::vec3 end_pt1      = .....;

double times;
double pos_rel   = modf(time_s / motiontime_s, &times);
float  w         = pos_rel < 0.5 ? (float)pos_rel * 2.0f : (float)(1.0 - pos_rel) * 2.0f;
glm::vec3 trans1 = start_pt1 * (w-1.0f) + end_pt1*w;

glm::vec3 start_pt2 = glm::vec3(  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
glm::vec3 end_pt2   = glm::vec3(  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
glm::vec3 trans2    = start_pt2 * (w-1.0f) + end_pt2*w;

glm::mat4 model1( 1.0f );
model1 = glm::translate( model1, trans1 );
model1 = glm::rotate( model1, glm::radians(angle_deg), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) );
model1 = glm::scale( model1, glm::vec3(....) );

glm::mat4 model2( 1.0f );
model2 = glm::translate( model2, trans2 );
model2 = glm::rotate( model2, glm::radians(-angle_deg), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) );
model2 = glm::scale( model2, glm::vec3(....) );

// Object 1
glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model1));
glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, NumVertices);

// Object 2
glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model2));
glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, NumVertices);
```

The result may look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an object whose centre is `C{cx, cy}`. You want to draw that object rotated and translated to another point. So you have two transformations: rotation and translation.

The point is those transformations are NOT commutative. Order matters.

Rotating (2D, for simplicity) around a point depends on where the object is relative to the point. Earth rotates around Sun, but also around itself. The result for each rotation is different.

If you want your polygon to rotate around its centre (again, for simple understanding) then you need:

1. Translate the polygon to the center of rotation, this is `C{cx,cy}`.
2. Then rotate it.
3. Then translate to the point where it was before step 1, or to the new point you want (along the X-axis in your case).